# SQL Server ALTER COLUMN and dependencies

Tags: sql-server, dependencies, alter-column

I want to increase the size of a `varchar` column in `table A`. This table has a lot of dependencies like stored procedures that update this column. If I increase and NOT decrease the size of this `varchar`, will it break any dependencies? As in will it cause the stored procedures that update this column to fail and give an error when called?

Answer (score 0):

If you are updating this column then no it will not give any errors as you are increasing the size only instance that you may run into trouble is if you are using the values within that column to insert in a smaller sized varchar within another table or a variable.